# Form fields lose focus when input value changes

Tags: forms, reactjs, jsonschema

I'm trying to build a form with conditional fields from a JSON schema using [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) and [react-jsonschem-form-conditionals](https://github.com/RxNT/react-jsonschema-form-conditionals).

The components I'm rendering are a `FormWithConditionals` and a `FormModelInspector`. The latter is a very simple component that shows the form model.

[image: screen shot 2018-02-01 at 17 50 32]

The relevant source code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Engine from "json-rules-engine-simplified";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
import applyRules from "react-jsonschema-form-conditionals";

function FormModelInspector (props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={props.onChange} checked={props.showModel}/>
          Show Form Model
        </label>
      </div>
      {
        props.showModel && <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.formData, null, 2)}</pre>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

class ConditionalForm extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formData: {},
      showModel: true
    };
    this.handleFormDataChange = this.handleFormDataChange.bind(this);
    this.handleShowModelChange = this.handleShowModelChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleShowModelChange (event) {
    this.setState({showModel: event.target.checked});
  }

  handleFormDataChange ({formData}) {
    this.setState({formData});
  }

  render () {
    const schema = {
      type: "object",
      title: "User form",
      properties: {
        nameHider: {
          type: 'boolean',
          title: 'Hide name'
        },
        name: {
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Name'
        }
      }
    };

    const uiSchema = {};

    const rules = [{
      conditions: {
        nameHider: {is: true}
      },
      event: {
        type: "remove",
        params: {
          field: "name"
        }
      }
    }];

    const FormWithConditionals = applyRules(schema, uiSchema, rules, Engine)(Form);

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FormWithConditionals schema={schema}
                uiSchema={uiSchema}
                formData={this.state.formData}
                onChange={this.handleFormDataChange}
                noHtml5Validate={true}>
          </FormWithConditionals>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FormModelInspector formData={this.state.formData}
                              showModel={this.state.showModel}
                              onChange={this.handleShowModelChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ConditionalForm.propTypes = {
  schema: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  uiSchema: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  rules: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

ConditionalForm.defaultProps = {
  uiSchema: {},
  rules: []
};
```

However, every time I change a field's value, the field loses focus. I suspect the cause of the problem is something in the `react-jsonschema-form-conditionals` library, because if I replace `<FormWithConditionals>` with `<Form>`, the problem does not occur.

If I remove the handler `onChange={this.handleFormDataChange}` the input field no longer loses focus when it's value changes (but removing this handler breaks the `FormModelInspector`).

### Aside

In the code above, if I remove the handler `onChange={this.handleFormDataChange}`, the `<FormModelInspector>` is not updated when the form data changes. I don't understand why this handler is necessary because the `<FormModelInspector>` is passed a reference to the form data via the `formData` attribute. Perhaps it's because every change to the form data causes a new object to be constructed, rather than a modification of the same object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is pretty straightforward, you are creating a `FormWithConditionals` component in your render method and in your `onChange` handler you `setState` which triggers a re-render and thus a new instance of `FormWithConditionals` is created and hence it loses focus. You need to move this instance out of render method and perhaps out of the component itself since it uses static values.

As `schema`, `uiSchema` and `rules` are passed as props to the `ConditionalForm`, you can create an instance of `FormWithConditionals` in `constructor` function and use it in render like this

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import Engine from "json-rules-engine-simplified";
    import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
    import applyRules from "react-jsonschema-form-conditionals";

    function FormModelInspector (props) {

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={props.onChange} checked={props.showModel}/>
              Show Form Model
            </label>
          </div>
          {
            props.showModel && <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.formData, null, 2)}</pre>
          }
        </div>
      )
    }


    class ConditionalForm extends React.Component {

      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          formData: {},
          showModel: true
        };
        const { schema, uiSchema, rules } = props;
        this.FormWithConditionals = applyRules(schema, uiSchema, rules, Engine)(Form);
        this.handleFormDataChange = this.handleFormDataChange.bind(this);
        this.handleShowModelChange = this.handleShowModelChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleShowModelChange (event) {
        this.setState({showModel: event.target.checked});
      }

      handleFormDataChange ({formData}) {
        this.setState({formData});
      }

      render () {
        const FormWithConditionals = this.FormWithConditionals;
        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <FormWithConditionals schema={schema}
                    uiSchema={uiSchema}
                    formData={this.state.formData}
                    onChange={this.handleFormDataChange}
                    noHtml5Validate={true}>
              </FormWithConditionals>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <FormModelInspector formData={this.state.formData}
                                  showModel={this.state.showModel}
                                  onChange={this.handleShowModelChange}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ConditionalForm.propTypes = {
      schema: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      uiSchema: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      rules: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    ConditionalForm.defaultProps = {
      uiSchema: {},
      rules: []
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try out your suggestion tomorrow and accept your answer if it works. Can you explain what you mean by "it uses static values like"?

Comment: apply rules takes object whose values are simple constant strings and none of it depends on a variable

Comment: This change you proposed - moving `applyRules` outside the `ConditionalForm` component - doesn't work because the `schema`, `uiSchema` and `rules` arguments of `applyRules` are props of the `ConditionalForm` component.

Comment: In your question, you have mentioned them as constant right??

Comment: `schema`, `uiSchema` and `rules` are constants, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @Dónal, yes that is that I am asking, they are defined as const in ConditionalForm and not as props to it

Comment: Let me know if you are still not able to solve the problem

Comment: Your updated answer solved the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated since React 16.3

Comment: @ml242 , Thanks, I updated  my answer for the same. However, componentWillMount is not deprecated in version 16.3, It can still be used and only from version 17 is react planning to deprecate it

Comment: I've tried this solution but I struggle with the form loosing focus on the first change, e.g. entering a letter in a field (after I then resume focus manually, it works as intended). Any idea what might be driving this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone bumping into the same problem but using Hooks, here's how without a class :

Just use a variable declared outside the component and initialize it inside `useEffect`. (don't forget to pass `[]` as second parameter to tell react that we do not depend on any variable, replicating the `componentWillMount` effect)

```js
// import ...
import Engine from 'json-rules-engine-simplified'
import Form from 'react-jsonschema-form'

let FormWithConditionals = () => null

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {
    formData,
    schema,
    uischema,
    rules,
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    FormWithConditionals = applyRules(schema, uischema, rules, Engine)(Form)
  }, [])

  return (
    <FormWithConditionals>
      <div></div>
    </FormWithConditionals>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring `function FormModelInspector` as an arrow func :

```
const FormModelInspector = props => (
    <div>
      <div className="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={props.onChange} checked={props.showModel}/>
          Show Form Model
        </label>
      </div>
      {
        props.showModel && <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.formData, null, 2)}</pre>
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: @Dónal I maybe misunderstood what you said in your 'Aside', but declaring this function as a stateless component or a pureComponent can prevent some unnecessary render(). Actually i think your issue is the way you construct your FormWithConditionals, i'll update my answer if the other one don't work for you.

Comment: Redefining `FormModelInspector` as an arrow function didn't change anything